# C++ binary file character replacement

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have a file which is read in as binary.  It has some basic plain text at the top and image data after.  Due to a process I cannot control I need to ensure that a certain string of characters is not present in the plain text representation of the data.  Meaning that if you opened the image data as plain text and the character sequence was present that is a problem.  My thought was to read in the data, convert to hex, and replace the the instances of that sequence.  The process would then be reversed to restore the file.

```
std::ifstream stream;
std::stringstream ss;
if (stream.bad())
  do.something();

length = stream.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::end);
data = new char[length];
stream.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::beg);
stream.read(data, length);
stream.close();

ss << std::hex;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)data[i];
const std::string& tmp = ss.str();
const char* cstr = tmp.c_str();

CString hexStr(cstr);
```

This reads the top portion of the file fine but introduces 'FF' characters into the rest of the data.  My c++ isn't great so I'm looking for some help as to why and how to correctly do this.  The rest looks like:

```
hexStr.Replace(character sequence to replace, replacement);
std::ofstream datafile(pathToFile, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::out);
char buf[3];
buf[2] = 0;
std::stringstream input(hexStr.GetString());
input.flags(std::ios_base::hex);
while (input)
{
    input >> buf[0] >> buf[1];
    long val = strtol(buf, nullptr, 16);
    datafile << static_cast<unsigned char>(val & 0xff);
}
```

Comment: Why in hex? Is there some reason why you can't do a plain string replacement?

Comment: Of course a string slurped from a binary file would have null-chars in it, so you have to use the two-arg constructor of std::string feeding it (data, length) - [see note 4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). After that you can treat it as a normal string.

Comment: Hex was due to some visual comparisons being done before but you're right it's not necessary.  I was just stuck in that thought process.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on that second comment?  I'm not entirely sure I understand.  If I create the result string from the two argument constructor won't it be the incorrect size?  The additional null-chars make the result longer than the original file.

Comment: `stream.read(data, length); std::string work(data,length); //now you can do the replacement on work...` if you do `std::string x(data)` then x will end when it encounters the first 0-byte.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and replace the isolated code fragments with a single [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, and compile, run, and reproduce your results?